# What are "ceremonial reasons"?

Tags: meaning

I saw following today:

> [Removed for Ceremonial Reasons]

What does it mean by "ceremonial reasons"?

It was originally in SO post, where content was removed. But I am interested more in general sense:

- Does it have multiple meanings?
- In what context it can be used?

Comment: Can you give more context? Was this on a plaque? In a program guide? In a set of instructions?

Comment: Hard to say without more context, but it's likely a euphemism, meaning roughly "because it was offensive" or "because it didn't suit our arguments".

Comment: It was SO post, where author removed the content.

Comment: In that case it was likely because he realized it was wrong.

Comment: I have heard, for example, of a building being closed to the public "for Ceremonial Reasons", *i.e.* because it was being used for a special ceremony; or of objects being removed, hidden or covered "for Ceremonial Reasons", *e.g.* of a Christian Cross being removed or covered because the building was being used for other purposes or by non-Christians. But content of a post being removed "for Ceremonial Reasons"???  It rather implies that the content should be restored when the ceremony has been completed!

Comment: @TrevorD Does that mean that "ceremonial reasons" is only used in the context when something is removed/closed/unaccessible?

Comment: @user694733 "Ceremonial reasons" is not a fixed phrase in English, any more than "insightful commentary" is. Obviously, the idea of "insightful commentary" makes sense, but it's just two words our together to describe something. What that thing is, we can't tell you without more context. So it goes with "ceremonial reasons". We don't know what it's talking about. All we can tell you is the reasons were ceremonial.

Comment: Was it ceremoniously deleted as some sort of rite of disassociation? Do you know what it was?

Comment: @DanBron I think you answered my question there: *"not a fixed phrase in English"*. I was originally looking for some meaning in that sentence that could work without the context, but seems I was wrong. You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @user694733 I'm in the camp on SE who holds "there is no answer to your Q" as not a useful answer to post, but you may feel free to post your own self-answer based on my comment. In re: "hoping it could work without context", a good test for whether a phrase is an English idiom or not is to look it up in a dictionary. If you don't find it, chances are slim that it's a well-established idiom someone could tell you the meaning of without context. Another clue is if you ask for the meaning for a phrase without context, and the first few commentors ask you to add context, then it's not an idiom.

Comment: @user694733 No, you could presumably have flags or other objects flown or put in place for ceremonial reasons.  I was merely responding to the Q. which was about 'removal'.